# How to add body title to Fprintf output?

Tags: go

I'm trying to add `<title>Go</title>` to my code example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func favicon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "favicon.ico")
}

func sayhelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    hostname, _ := os.Hostname()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n\nSystem info:\nHostname [pod name]: %s", hostname)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\nCurrent URL: %s\n", r.Host)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", favicon)
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayhelloName)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

I tried to add like:
`fmt.Fprintf(w, "<title>Go</title>")`. It works but make mess with strings next to. I wouldn't like to use html template only to add title to page. Is there any ways to add title in one string?

Comment: Read the docs for the `fmt` package you're using. `Fprintf` is for *format strings*. You're not using any formatting directives to print the title. You can just use `Fprint`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

not used html template. just used only fmt.Fprintf.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func favicon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "favicon.ico")
}

func sayhelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    hostname, _ := os.Hostname()

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<html>")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<head>")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<title>%s</title>", "Go")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "</head>")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<body>")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>System info: Hostname [pod name]: %s", hostname)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Current URL: %s", r.Host)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "</body>")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "</html>")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", favicon)
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayhelloName)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```